# How do i make a form around a div box

Tags: html, css, image, submit, vertical-alignment

I created a small box div containing an image and a text beside each other. But I don't know how I can add a form around it that when I hover on any part of the box it would click on submit.

```css
.trust-box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="trust-box">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/34299/herbs-flavoring-seasoning-cooking.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="trust" width="50" height="50">
  <span>Portis Wallet</span>
</div>
```

And again how do I make the image and the text align horizontally inside the box? [The div box image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qrhuw.png).

Answer (score 1):

Research `mouseenter` for adding an event listener for hovering. For aligning your elements you can make use of `flexbox`. See the snippet below:

```css
.trust-box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="trust-box">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/34299/herbs-flavoring-seasoning-cooking.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="trust" width="50" height="50">
  <span>Portis Wallet</span>
</div>
```

More on `flexbox` [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 0):

You should try making it a button

```
<button type="button" class="trust-box">
  Portis Wallet
  <img src="images/Portis.png" alt="trust" width="50" height="50">
</button>
```

Aligning the image you can try either `margin-top` or `top`

Comment: Thanks. But when i changed it to button as above. Everything was distorted in the media queries as i try to adjust my screen width to fit different sizes

Comment: How do i fix that?

Comment: It's not just a single button. They are display as  a flex on a whole page. lIke 60 of them on a row of 4mdisplayed as a flex

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the button width to it fits different screen sizes?

Comment: Yeah. I did but still not working

Comment: @media(max-width: 1025px) {
    .trust-box{
        width: 40%;
    }
    
}


@media(max-width: 768px) {
    .trust-box{
        width: 90%;
        
    
    }
}

@media(max-width: 480px) {
    h1{
        font-size: 3rem;
    }

    .paragraph-long{
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
}

Comment: Or is there anything am not doing right?

Comment: And they were functioning better before i added the button tag

Comment: I've tested your media and it seems to work fine, I'm unable to see how this might not be working for you could you send a picture of it not working properly? Or share a link to more code?

Comment: [link](https://vast-refuge-11255.herokuapp.com)

Comment: Have sent the link.

Comment: Note that the max-screen width of my laptop is 1115px

Comment: Definitely can see the problem now, I've tried some different ideas for adjust width so it stays responsive. This is what I came up with which seems to work for all widths and it is no longer distorted.

@media(max-width: 1025px) { 
    .trust-box{ 
        width: 18vw;
    } 
} 
@media(max-width: 768px) { 
    .trust-box{ 
        width: 260px; 
    } 
} 
@media(max-width: 480px) { 
    h1{ 
        font-size: 3rem; 
    } 
    .paragraph-long{ 
        font-size: 1.5rem; 
    } 
}
With vw it uses device width to set responsive width. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank. It worked

Comment: Please. Another thing is that i tried to post data from my app.js file  to my MailChimp but i couldn't see any data there. I was having two post route in the app.js file , I 
 realised that the moment I clicked the submit button to take me to the next page where i would submit my form. And I went to check my Mailchimp I couldn't see the email and name submitted on my Mailchimp

Comment: When I removed the post to take me to the form page. I realized that I can now see the form submitted on my Mailchimp. But now I couldn't get to the form page from the previous page and i need to click the submit to  go to the form page. Please how do I rectify this?

Comment: The codes is quite lengthy. I should have paste it here.  But i t has surpassed the requird amount